# How to get current PHP page name

Tags: php

I've a file called `demo.php` where I don't have any GET variables in the URL, so if I want to hide a button if am on this page I can't use something like this:

```
if($_GET['name'] == 'value') {
  //Hide
} else {
  //show
}
```

So I want something like

```
$filename = //get file name
if($filename == 'file_name.php') {
  //Hide
} else {
  //show
}
```

I don't want to declare unnecessary GET variables just for doing this...

Answer (score 352, accepted):

You can use `basename()` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to get current page file name

```
echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); /* Returns The Current PHP File Name */
```

Comment: what if url is `abc.php?blah=demo` or `abc.php\a\b?` because I just need abc,php

Comment: you'll get `abc.php` :)

Comment: Also...You can replace the `.php` extension and hyphens
`ucwords( str_ireplace(array('-', '.php'), array(' ', ''), basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ) )`
and Capitalize Words with `ucwords` or first letter using `ucfirst`.
Maybe somebody will need this...

Comment: If you do not want the `.php` extension you may use `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php')`

Comment: if you do not want the file extension, you can also use `pathinfo(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), PATHINFO_FILENAME);`

Answer (score 32):

`$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];` will give you the current filename and its path, but `basename(__FILE__)` should give you the filename that it is called from.

So

```
if(basename(__FILE__) == 'file_name.php') {
  //Hide
} else {
  //show
}
```

should do it.

Answer (score 11):

In your case you can use `__FILE__` variable !
It should help.
It is one of predefined.
Read more about predefined constants in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php