# PHP_SELF returning 's' string on localhost

Tags: php, localhost

I am using this code to highlight the active link in navigation, but the code is not working. When I `echo   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` this, it gives 's' string as the output on localhost. Please help, what is wrong here?

P.S. Also when I checked apache error.log it is showing:

```
[Wed Feb 19 18:28:08.671229 2014] [:error] [pid 1353] [client 127.0.0.1:57968] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'PHP_SELF'
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

```
<li <?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "index.php"){ echo 'class="active"';}?> > <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
```

Comment: I don't think you can use php within  a <li> opening tag. this will most likely not solve the problem but it is a start.

Comment: We can use php code any where in the HTML :-)

Comment: yes in the html, but this is within the <li> tag, put it in front of it or behind it or something.

Comment: @Goosebumbs your comments are not legit. You can use PHP anywhere in HTML(as long as the extension is PHP or your Apache settings are edited to accept PHP in other extension).

Comment: @nevermind like I said, I don't think it will solve the problem. but I'm pretty sure some browsers won't properly run this code.

Comment: @user3328295 Could you give the output? You've certainly forgot a space before `class="active"`

Comment: @Goosebumbs I've made a fiddle for you to prove it: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ju1-v0g

Comment: @GuyT I like how you try to proof something and you don't even close your <li> opening tag.

Comment: @Goosebumbs Please read again. It's closed in the `echo`. Maybe you need to learn PHP(and what Server Side Scripting means).

Comment: @Goosebumbs, all browsers will run this code, OP just adding class="active" to li tag.

Comment: @GuyT your </li> close tag seems to think differently

Comment: and even if it works fine, why would you put it there?

Comment: @nicezeal, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032930/how-to-get-current-php-page-name

Comment: @nevermind Thanks !!  but basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); i have tried this already

Comment: @nicezeal What does `print_r($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` print?

Comment: @GuyT It prints string 's'

Comment: @GuyT Actually this list code i have included in header.php file and that header.php file i have included index.php may be this is causing error can you help me with this "making active" problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have mentioned in your last comment, you used the PHP_SELF in the header.php file so the which is calling PHP_SELF, it returns that filename. So use that in your index.php file at the top of every code:

```
<?php $filename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>
```

and then use the $filename variable in your header.php file. may be this will help. let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li <?php if(substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 1) == "index.php"){ echo 'class="active"';}?> > <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
```

Check if this works for you.