# How do I excluding INDEX or Home page in PHP Code?

Tags: php

I know nothing about PHP. I have the code below to show next and prev at the bottom of each page, with <-|-> as a separator **but** I don't want it on the home/index page.

```
<div align="center" >
<?php echo previous_page_not_post(); ?> <-|->  <?php echo next_page_not_post(); ?>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an if statement like this:

```
<div align="center">
<?php
    if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != "index.php") {
        echo previous_page_not_post()." <-|-> ".next_page_not_post();
    }
?>
</div>
```

(Look at [get current php page name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032930/how-to-get-current-php-page-name))