# How to get last part of a URL derived from $_GET

Tags: php, get

Lets say I have this page:
`example.com/state/california`
and I use `$_GET` to retrieve that specific page from the DB.

However when I try this page:
`example.com/state/new%20york`
My page seems to only retrieve "new" instead of "new york"

htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^state/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) location.php?state=$1 [NC,L]
```

Code:

```
<? 
$state = $_GET['state'];
$sql = "
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        states
    WHERE
        state = '$state'
    ";

$records = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

$sql = "
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        states
    WHERE
        state='$state' LIMIT 1
    ";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows < 1) {
    echo $state;
    exit();
} else {
    echo "Welcome to the state of ".$state;
}
?>
```

I'm not looking for the file name, I'm looking for the last part of the loaded semantic URL.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current PHP page name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032930/how-to-get-current-php-page-name)

Comment: is there a router involved? or a simple .htaccess REWRITE? Not enough information there to help you...

Comment: .htaccess

    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^state/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) location.php?state=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: `<?

$state = $_GET['state'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM states WHERE state = '$state'";
$records = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM states WHERE state='$state' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrows < 1){
    echo $state;
    exit(); 
} else {
    echo "Welcome to the state of ".$state;
}


?>`

Comment: Sorry guys for the code layout :(

Comment: @Mike - Posted code

Comment: @ObsidianAge - not looking for file name

Comment: @Jeff - Posted htaccess

Comment: 1) Your code should be in the edited original question 2) Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection (hint: use prepared statements)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `%20` is "breaking" the chain.  I.e. your htaccess doesn't see what comes after this as being part of the same block as that which precedes it.
I would suggest creating a function to replace white spaces with an underscore or a  hyphen

Comment: Could you provide an example in which I can replace white spaces with a hyphen

It would be awesome if I could use this as an example
example.com/state/new-york

Comment: You'd need to do this when creating the link that takes users to the page in question.  So, I'd go with
`$url=str_replace(" ","-",$state);`

Comment: This code worked however
example.com/state/new-york still returns "new"

Comment: It seems like the hypen is also breaking the chain, why is this happening?

Comment: Try changing `RewriteRule ^state/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)` to `RewriteRule ^state/(.*)`

Comment: If this does work, please make sure you put some kind of protection on your SQL statement to prevent MySQL injection.  Otherwise, anyone could include SQL in the URL and this would then get executed by your PHP.
For example, you could have an array of possible states and if the value of `$_GET['state']` is not found inside that array then don't execute the SQL